# Перевод массива char в строку

Tags: java

Не понимаю почему такой вот вывод:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(temp[i]);
}
```

Сильно отличается от вот такого:

```
System.out.println(temp.toString());
```

В первом случае массив символов отображается как надо, а во втором показывает не символы, а байты. Как тогда перевсти массив `char`'ов в строку правильно ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Массив символов (`char[]`), не является строковым классом (`String`).

Для конвертации массива символов в строку, необходимо создать эту строку из массива символов.

```
String myStr = new String(temp);
```

А потом выводить её как обычную строку

```
System.out.println(myStr);
```

**UPD от Artem Konovalov**

Метод `.toString()` возвращает представление класса + хэшкод объекта в шестнадцатиричном представлении

`return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

Comment: Небольшая поправка, toString на массиве вернет представление класса + хэшкод объекта в шестнадцатиричном представлении, но никак не адрес первого элемента массива. `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

Comment: Точно, а уже подумал, что это `C++` какой-то. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char [] strText = text.toCharArray();
//или ваш метод которым вы получаете массив символов
String.valueOf(strToPrint);
//возвращает строку состоящую из символов массива char [] strToPrint
```